# Include url helpers in graphql-ruby resolvers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm trying to access url helpers from `resolve` methods in [graphql-ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby) to generate fields like `url`. I know I can do this:

```
EventType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  field :url, !types.String do
    resolve ->(event, _args, _ctx) do
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path event
    end
  end
end
```

I know it's possible to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in your models to avoid prefixing every call but how to do this with graphql-ruby?

Additionally, if I call `event_url`, it doesn't have host and port. Obviously, I'd like to avoid adding `host: request.host` to every helper call.

Answer (score 8):

I've solved it by creating `config/initializers/graphql.rb` that injects `url_helpers` into the resolver's context:

```
module GraphQL
  module Define
    class DefinedObjectProxy
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    end
  end
end
```

As for the host and port, it looks like

```
# Allow to build url from models or graphql without needing to pass host/port every time
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

does the trick. I've inserted this into a separate initializer although I suspect adding it to `config/routes.rb` would work, too.

Comment: You can also `include ActionController::Helpers` for other helpers you're used to having available in controllers.

Comment: How can I use rails helpers in resolver classes for example?